# Compile quickfix without mysql

Tags: quickfix

I want to compile quickfix library, I don't have any MySQL installed on my computer and it is not necessary for me. I tried to disable the mysql from the configure --without-mysql but when I compile, I still see -lmysqlclient in my compiling command and it eventually fails because I don't have this library file. How can I disable this?

Also, if I tried to compile with old gcc4.1.2 (newer version like 4.8 is fine), but I cannot even generate the configure file but keeps seeing this error:

```
 configure: error: unable to find set_terminate in std or global namespace
```

There should be any problem with this compiler because I can compile many other things and I have to use this version of the compiler because many of my libraries are compiled under this version.

Comment: What programming language.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you want to compile C++ source codes - http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/building.html. The tutorial indicates that MySQL is optional. To install MySQL support, you need to explicitly add `--with-mysql` flag. There is not `--without-mysql` flag.